# В jsp не работают переменные

Tags: jsp, jstl

Такой код:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach items="${zayavkas}" var="zayavka">
    ${zayavka.id}
    ${zayavka.fullName}
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

При загрузке страницы вместо значений переменных отображаются ${zayavka.id} ${zayavka.fullName}. Дебаггером проходил код в zayavkas, - приходят все записи. Как сделать так, чтобы выводились значения?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51299/discussion-on-question-by-iosif-serbskiy--jsp---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
   <c:forEach items="${zayavkas}" var="zayavka">
    <tr>${zayavka.id}</tr>
    <tr>${zayavka.fullName}</tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Тогда уж `<c:out value="${zayavka.id}"/>`. `<tr>` нисколько не поможет, но усугубит запросто.

Comment: @Sergey, проверял на своем примере, без tr отображалось: zayavka.id, а с tr переданное значение

Comment: @Sergey. чем tr может усугубить, если это просто разметка страницы?

Comment: Многим как мне `<tr>` нужен только а таблице. И более того, внутри `<tr>` должны быть только `<td>` и `<th>`. Таблица не нужна - не нужны и `<tr>`. Вы конечно же можете применять всякое первое пришедшее на ум, подменить пустяковую проблему другой, хотя теперь не заметной, но более серьёзной. Да пожалуйста. До первого облома.

Comment: Попробывал:${zayavka.id} ${zayavka.fullName}

Comment: https://github.com/VladKazakov/VCB_JNDI_2.git